# Listings disappear when item moved to submenu

Tags: structure

I have 20 years experience developing LAMP apps, but I'm new to Expression Engine. I'm helping someone edit a site that was abandoned by the developer.

The site uses EE2 with the Structure module. They had a parent-level item that displayed listings. When I make it a sub-menu item to another parent-level item, the listings disappear. It says no listings found, even though I created a channel associated to that listing category.

Also, I see a lot of help being offered to use this or that code, but I can't tell where the template is that governs the layout of that page.

Can someone point me in the right direction to understanding this?

Thanks,

Bill

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I found the template and discovered that the developer was finding listings based on the url segment, which was now 2 instead of 1...

Bill